# AngularJS, how to send url unfriendly requests?

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to tie up a PHP backend (MySQL database) and an AngularJS front end.
I've spend about two days reading through tutorials to much frustration and time.

Basically I'm using the line:

```
$http.get('/angular/index.php').success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Which makes the following request:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/angular/index.php 404 (Not Found)
```

Problem is the service is only accessible from:

```
angular/index.php
```

How do I change/use Angular to send requests to local data storage/database ??

RESTful settings

Virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:9000>
    ServerAdmin webadmin
    DocumentRoot "/Users/biggles/Sites/angular/app/ajax"
    ServerName angular
    ServerAlias angular
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/angular-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/angular-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   angular
```

Comment: Are you saying your PHP backend is running on a different port (80)? If so, you're going to have to use absolute URIs in your front-end (`http://localhost/angular/index.php`) as well as setup the appropriate [CORS headers in your backend](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server)

Comment: Does the page load when you access it through your browser in localhost?

Comment: Alternately, simply move your Angular app into the PHP document root instead of using the node HTTP server and open it there (`http://localhost/index.html` or whatever your Angular main file is called)

Comment: It loads when I run it in the browser as 'angular/index.php'. I cannot use http:// because it's local so I'm not sure what you mean by using absolute paths when 'angular/index.php' should be one; there is no way of specifying this in angular?

Comment: I'll try to explain. It appears your angular app is running on port 9000 (probably via some NodeJS based HTTP server). Your PHP app appears to be running on the default port 80 (that is, if you access it via `http://localhost/angular/index.php` then it's port 80). The port difference might as well make them running on different servers on different sides of the planet as far as JavaScript and HTTP requests are concerned. Either run them on the same port (pretty simple really) or do as I suggested in my first comment

Comment: I've made some edits, and changed the port onto 9000. Still failing.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. You have a host named `angular`. This is as big a disparity as the port. For simple HTTP communication in JavaScript, **everything** must match; scheme (http / https), host name and port. If they don't (and you can't put them on the same service), you'll have to use CORS (or JSONP but CORS is simpler). Your front-end will have to make requests to `http://angular/index.php`. FYI, you won't be able to run two different services on the same port. I don't know why you don't just move the angular app into `/Users/biggles/Sites/angular/app/ajax`

Comment: Can you answer with the correct configuration as the app is inside that folder and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access `http://angular/index.php` from your angular app you can just use the following snippet, as 
`angular` is your hostname and not part of the path

```
$http.get('/index.php').success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Angular $http service acts just like usual links would:

If your url starts with a scheme name eg. `http://` or `//` $http will try to do an external request. However this requires a CORS  configuration or JSONP.

If your url starts with a slash `/` $http will use the current scheme name, user info, hostname and port but will replace the full path.

If your url starts with neither a scheme name nor a slash your path will be relative.

From wikipedia:

```
foo://username:password@example.com:8042/over/there/index.dtb?type=animal&name=narwhal#nose
 \_/  \_______________/ \_________/ \__/                      \______________________/ \__/
  |           |               |       |                                  |              |
  |       userinfo         hostname  port                              query        fragment
  |    \________________________________/\___________________/ 
scheme                 |                          |              
 name              authority                      |              
                                                path             
\_______________________________________/                   
                     |                                      
                    host
```